# Popover on input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried looking at previous solutions but none of them have worked.

I'm trying to have a popover show up to the left after clicking on the input field.

HTML:

```
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Type your full name" rel="popover">
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#name').popover({'title': 'Name tooltip'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake by me. I wasn't loading the JavaScript files from the right directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `placement:left` when you init the popover it should work. Is your popover not working at all, or just not on the left?

And, don't forget the document.ready..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#name').popover({title:'Name tooltip',placement:'left'});
});
```

**Demo**: http://bootply.com/61386

Answer (score 0):

qTip is nice! Version 2 is out: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Comment: What does this have to do with my question

Comment: It's a jquery plugin that contains all the functionality you'd need. Already written for you and ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#name").popover({title: "Name tooltip"});
</script>
```